# SharpPcap/C# Проблема с открытием интерфейса enp3s0

Tags: c#, .net

есть следующий код:

```
using SharpPcap;

CaptureDeviceList devicesList = CaptureDeviceList.Instance;

ICaptureDevice captureDevice = devicesList[0];

captureDevice.OnPacketArrival += new

PacketArrivalEventHandler(Program_onPacketArrival);

captureDevice.Open();

captureDevice.Filter = "(tcp src port 15203) and (greater 360 and less 420)";

captureDevice.Capture();

static void Program_onPacketArrival(object sender, SharpPcap.PacketCapture e)
{
   var packet = e.GetPacket();

   System.Console.WriteLine(packet);
}
```

Я пытаюсь сниффить tcp пакеты по интерфейсу enp3s0, но при открытие данного интерфейса, возникает исключение:
"Unhandled exception. SharpPcap.PcapException: Unable to activate the adapter (enp3s0). (Error Code: PermissionDenied)
at SharpPcap.LibPcap.LibPcapLiveDevice.Open(DeviceConfiguration configuration)
at SharpPcap.CaptureDeviceExtensions.Open(IPcapDevice device, DeviceModes mode, Int32 read_timeout)
at Program.$(String[] args) in /home/.../VSCodeProjects/stud/Program.cs:line 15".


 **Среда выполнение кода**: vs code

 **Ядро os**: Linux 5.15.0-87-generic

 **Версия пакета SharpPcap**: 6.2.5

 **Версия платформы .NET**: 6.0


 Какие есть варианты решение данной проблемы?

Comment: Запустить от админской учетки пробовали?

Comment: tym32167, из под root? если да то безрезультатно, если именно проект запускать с команды dotnet run

Comment: Гугл посылает сюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140999/unable-to-activate-the-adapter-by-using-npcap-instead-of-winpcap

Comment: Я там был уже и не раз, я без понятия как правильно установить драйвер Npcap 0.991 на платформу Linux, можно ещё попробовать воспользоваться утилитой setcap c такими разрешениями: "cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip" какому либо процессу или бинарному файлу, вопрос только какому